# XML tag has empty body less... (Ctrl+F1) Reports empty tag body. The validation works in XML / JSP / JSPX / HTML/ XHTML file types

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I'm looking for information, but do not quite understand the message refers.

I appreciate any help to know that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong here, as it reports it's a tag with empty body. You can close it by pressing `ALT` + `ENTER` and selecting `Collapse empty tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **self-closing tags**, for example:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/bannerAd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@+id/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
```